# equation problem

Tags: equations

I have this problem with this equation that i cannot find out:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}   

    \begin{document} 
    \begin{eqnarray*} 

        -\rho U_{\infty}^{2}Lb+\int\limits_{0}^{L}\rho u^{2}bdy+U_{\infty}(\rho U_{\infty}Lb-\int\limits_{0}^{L}\rho ubdy=-D \Rightarrow \\ 

        -\cancel{\rho U_{\infty}^{2}Lb}+\int\limits_{0}^{L}\rho u^{2}bdy+\cancel{\rho U_{\infty}^{2}Lb}-U_{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{L}\rho ubdy=-D \Rightarrow \\ 

        \frac{\rho\int\limits_{0}^{L}(u^{2}-uU_{\infty})bdy}{\frac{\rho}{2}U_{\infty}^{2}bc}=
        \frac{-D}{\frac{\rho}{2}U_{\infty}^{2}bc}\Rightarrow \\ 

        c_{D}=\frac{2}{c}\int\limits_{0}^{L}\frac{u}{U_{\infty}}(1-\frac{u}{U_{\infty}})dy \\

        \end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please complete your code to provide a Minimal (non-)Working Example i.e. a complete, small document people can use to reproduce the error? Could you also explain what the problem actually is?

Comment: Remove the blank lines. Or put a comment character at the start of each one if you want to keep them to visually separate things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the blank lines will compile the code. However, it might be better to use one of the environments provided by the AMS packages since `eqnarray` has some issues. (See the AMS package manual for details.) For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,cancel}
\begin{document}

  \begin{gather*}
    -\rho U_{\infty}^{2}Lb+\int\limits_{0}^{L}\rho u^{2}bdy+U_{\infty}(\rho U_{\infty}Lb-\int\limits_{0}^{L}\rho ubdy=-D \Rightarrow \\
    -\cancel{\rho U_{\infty}^{2}Lb}+\int\limits_{0}^{L}\rho u^{2}bdy+\cancel{\rho U_{\infty}^{2}Lb}-U_{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{L}\rho ubdy=-D \Rightarrow \\
    \frac{\rho\int\limits_{0}^{L}(u^{2}-uU_{\infty})bdy}{\frac{\rho}{2}U_{\infty}^{2}bc}=
    \frac{-D}{\frac{\rho}{2}U_{\infty}^{2}bc}\Rightarrow \\
    c_{D}=\frac{2}{c}\int\limits_{0}^{L}\frac{u}{U_{\infty}}(1-\frac{u}{U_{\infty}})dy
  \end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image: gathering]

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code (the presence of blank lines) has already been addressed in @cfr's answer. I'll add a few notes on fine points of math typesetting and efficient coding in TeX:

- To avoid having to write `\limits` after every single `\int` instruction, load with `amsmath` package with the option `intlimits`:

  ```
  \usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
  ```

  Note that this option only works on `\int` in displaystyle-mode.
- It's customary -- probably because it enhances readability/parsability -- to insert a thinspace, `\,`, between the integrand and the "dy" part of an integral expression. Some (many?) also like to typeset the "d" symbol in an upright shape to highlight its "math operator" function; others, though, don't follow this stylistic rule.
- In the final row, you should enlarge the parentheses that surround the term `1-\frac{u}{U_{\infty}}`, say, by writing `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)`. In this case, `\left(` and `\right)` would create parentheses are too large, visually/aesthetically speaking.
- It's probably a good idea to insert whitespace, say with `\quad`, before the `\Rightarrow` directives at the end of the first three lines. Doing so creates a bit more visual offset, making the `\Rightarrow` stand out a bit.
- There's a stray `(` symbol on the first line that should (probably?) be eliminated.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}   

\begin{document} 
\begin{gather*} 
-\rho U_{\infty}^{2}Lb+\int_{0}^{L}\rho u^{2}b\,dy+U_{\infty}\rho U_{\infty}Lb-\int_{0}^{L}\rho ub\,dy=-D \quad\Rightarrow \\ 
%
-\cancel{\rho U_{\infty}^{2}Lb}+\int_{0}^{L}\rho u^{2}b\,dy+\cancel{\rho U_{\infty}^{2}Lb}-U_{\infty}\int_{0}^{L}\rho ub\,dy=-D \quad\Rightarrow \\ 
%
\frac{\rho\int_{0}^{L}(u^{2}-uU_{\infty})b\,dy}{\frac{\rho}{2}U_{\infty}^{2}bc}=
\frac{-D}{\frac{\rho}{2}U_{\infty}^{2}bc}\quad\Rightarrow \\ 
%
c_{D}=\frac{2}{c}\int_{0}^{L}\frac{u}{U_{\infty}}
\Bigl(1-\frac{u}{U_{\infty}}\Bigr)\,dy \\
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```